# How to Create a Custom or Unique Neighborhood in NetLogo

Tags: unique, netlogo

1. In my project, I need to create a unique neighborhood governed by a rule. The default NL neighborhoods do not suit my purpose.

My rule is as follows.  Form a neighborhood of three patches as follows: 
a.  Begin at the origin on the bottom left corner. 
b.  Assign all patches a label in the form: Patch ”n” where “n” is any random number.
c.  Move in a clock wise direction
d.  Moving clockwise, select three patches such that they all border each other i.e. Patch 1 has a border with Patches 2 & 3, Patch 2 has a border with Patches 1 & 3 and patch 3 has borders with Patch 1 & 2.
e.  If there is more than one possible choice to form the group, select the patch where 
n” in the patch label is smallest.
f.  If for example I have a world of 100 patches with n=3, then this results in33 neighborhoods of three patches each and a 34th neighborhood of one patch.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you try anything by yourself? You can edit your question and post some code to show us what you have attempted.

Comment: I looked at the examples in NetLogo for neighborhoods and the inbuilt neighbors and neighbor4 functions.  However, these provide no insights as to how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Your requirements almost read like pseudo-code. Why don't you try to translate each of those statements in NetLogo code? Then, if you get stuck, you can ask a more specific question...

Comment: First: three squares on a 2D plane can not all share borders. You'd need offset squares, hex patches or some other geometry.  NetLogo "patches" are squares. Perhaps you don't mean the built-in patches, but rather some agent with a certain shape? Second: Clockwise? From noon? Third: your description doesn't make sense, and it sounds like it doesn't fill space completely, you will hava lots of single patches not in groups.

Comment: Please link to a drawing that demonstrates how these patches are generated, what a few of them look like. Imgur.com is a nice free image hosting site.

Comment: Please see image in link below.

http://imgur.com/ktC2jjR

Comment: Note that the following options are all valid neighborhoods for the first neighborhood in the diagram above

00 01 11;
00 01 10;

00 11 01;
00 11 10;

Comment: So how do you choose one of these four options?

Recall the rules.

1.  You start with 00 as the origin.
2. You go north - which means you can choose either 01 or 11.
3.  You decide between 01 and 11  by looking at the Patch labels. Recall each patch is first assigned a label in the form; "Box n".  So select the  patch with the lowest n.
4. Let's say 01 had label "Box 20" and 11 had label "Patch 30", you would choose 01 as 20 is less than 30.  At this point you now have made two choices:  00 and 01.

Comment: 5.  To get the third member, you see that you have only two possible options:  11 and 10.  How do you select the third member from these two options.  Again you use the label rule.

Comment: Stack Overflow permits editing questions. It would really help if you went back and rewrote your question to be clearer — it's very hard to piece together from the series of the comments.